# GORM, one-to-many saving whole object graph at once do not work, where is bug?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

**Problem:**
GORM is able to create (save) parent object with its child in one-to-many relation.
[Per this documentation example](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#cascades) But somewhere I my code is bug that make it impossible. Pls help me find it :|

**UPDATE:**
Found few miss-typed letters. (Since STS do not work on my PC...)
But problem remains the same. However I'm puzzled at suggestion which is given exception is thrown. Still need help.

**Parent model:**

```
package tanktactics

class Guide {
    String title
    Date created
    SortedSet chapters

    static hasMany = [chapters: Chapter] //changed to has

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Child model:**

```
package tanktactics

class Chapter implements Comparable {
    String title
    String content
    Integer sortOrder
    static belongsTo = [guide: Guide]

    static constraints = {
    }

    int compareTo(obj) {
        sortOrder.compareTo(obj.compareTo) //changed to sort
    }
}
```

**Printout from `grails console`:**

```
import tanktactics.Guide
import tanktactics.Chapter

some_guide = new Guide(title: "First guide!", created: new Date())
some_guide.addToChapters(new Chapter(title: "Ch II", content: "Lorem II", sortOrder:1))
    .addToChapters(new Chapter(title: "Ch I", content: "Lorem", sortOrder:0))
    .save()

some_guide.title
some_guide.chapters[0].title
some_guide.chapters[0].content
some_guide.chapters[1].title
some_guide.chapters[1].content

groovy> import tanktactics.Guide 
groovy> import tanktactics.Chapter 
groovy> some_guide = new Guide(title: "First guide!", created: new Date()) 
groovy> some_guide.addToChapters(new Chapter(title: "Ch II", content: "Lorem II", sortOrder:1)).addToChapters(new Chapter(title: "Ch I", content: "Lorem", sortOrder:0)).save() 
groovy> some_guide.title 
groovy> some_guide.chapters[0].title 
groovy> some_guide.chapters[0].content 
groovy> some_guide.chapters[1].title 
groovy> some_guide.chapters[1].content 

Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: tanktactics.Guide.addToChapters() is applicable for argument types: (tanktactics.Chapter) values: [tanktactics.Chapter : null]
Possible solutions: addToChapters(java.lang.Object), getChapters()
    at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:963)
    at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
    at temp_test.run(temp_test.groovy:6)
    at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
    at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1237)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you misspelled in Guide class. Possibly you mean **hasMany** instead of hadMany.

Comment: STS probably didn't show him the mistake. Happened to me many a times.

Comment: STS do not work for me... I got plenty of bugs on STS both on Win & Lin so I just work in vim & terminal. Thus this mistake... :|

Answer (score 1):

You should also put this code into your domain class (and in all other classes with hasMany properties):

```
static mapping = {
    chapters(cascade:"all-delete-orphan")
}
```

Comment: This should not be a problem, since if I add belongsTo, it have the same effect. And Grails will manage cascade updates/deletes/creation just fine. Only when one-to-many relation is unidirectional this code is needed. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I have updated code accordingly, maybe now you will be able to catch this bug.